# color of dendogram in heatmap

Tags: r, bioinformatics, heatmap, dendrogram

I used `heatmap.2(mat, Colv = TRUE, Rowv = TRUE)` to create a heatmap and got this: [image]

I have a group of vectors: `c("a","d"), c("b","c","e"),c("f","g")` and I want to allocate different color to each group, so that each member of a specific group in the dendogram will be colored in the specific color of its group.

Comment: I think THIS will be useful for you    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265536/how-to-color-the-branches-and-tick-labels-in-the-heatmap-2

Comment: Thanks. But the difference is that I can't choose the color for each column, just for the whole cluste,  and I want to divide the colores by vectors that represent the columns. @pali

Comment: Is [this](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ComplexHeatmap/inst/doc/s6.heatmap_decoration.html) what you're trying to do? Or do you want the heatmap itself to have different colours for different groups?

Comment: No. I want diffrent colors for different groups (that I will choose). @heathobrien

Comment: @user2026 That's clear. What I'm trying to figure out is what part of the plot are you trying to colour. The heatmap? The dendrogram? A strip between the heatmap and the column names? Something else?

Comment: The dendogram @heathobrien

Comment: In that case the solution linked by @pali will work for you. You just need to use the `branches_attr_by_labels` function from `dendextend`